# Allow Certain Special Characters In Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, backend

I am using mongo sanitize which filters the malicious characters. However, I want to allow '>' and '<' when working with req and res.
What is the possible way for this?
I could not find any libraries that provided this feature and mongo sanitize doesn't seem to have any functions regarding this issue.